# I want to increase pressure of water in a closed vessel

Tags: fluid-dynamics

I am trying to make a high pressure water jet using DIY hand pump which pushes water into a sealed vessel with non-return valve at the inlet. I am planning to do it by first closing the valve to the nozzle until i pump in enough water into the vessel so that pressure is created.then after open the nozzle valve to create a jet at very high pressure. I have never done it before, Is it possible? Please I need guidance...What is the maximum pressure I can raise? I need to raise upto 100 PSI. Thank you. I have attached a picture to illustrate the idea.[image]

Comment: Have you considered heating up the container?

Comment: Cross-posted (link only) to engineering.SE: http://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/8502/i-want-to-increase-pressure-of-water-in-a-closed-vessel

Answer (score 2):

I recommend that you add some air in your system. Water is mostly incompressible - so while you can raise the pressure to 100 psi quite easily, the moment you open the nozzle and a little bit of water leaves, the pressure will drop right down. As you add air, the air will expand and maintain pressure in the vessel (when the air volume doubles, the pressure will drop in half, roughly).

However, such air volume gives the system certain ballistic properties: if the pressure container fails, there will be more oomph behind the fragments flying around. Making good pressure vessels is not an amateur pastime.

The kind of thing you are looking for is commonly used with irrigation pumps - between the pump and the sprinkler is a vessel with an air bladder in it. As you pump water in, the air is compressed. This does exactly what you are talking about.

[Here is a link that describes this in more detail](http://www.sprinklerwarehouse.com/DIY-Pressure-tanks-s/7024.htm)

Comment: Thanks Floris, this was quite a great piece of information, I have already located where I can buy the diaphragm in my country, may be will need some more advice on building the vessel its self, so that its good enough. Lastly how do I incorporate the breather?

Comment: Should I fix it into the container/vessel itself or into the diaphragm? someone told me it can be used to add air into the vessel incase it goes down,  is it true?

Comment: The compressed air compartment needs to have both the ability to be pressurized, and a relief valve that will let out extra air in case pressure gets too high (for example if the temperature increases while the vessel is at max pressure). As I said before - making a pressure vessel is not really an amateur pastime. Depending on the size and pressure you want, could you use the principle of a water tower? The pressure is produced by gravity in that case - might be a safer option.